# The second addMapping() can not work using QDataWidgetMapper

Tags: qt, model-view-controller, model, pyqt, mapping

The second `addMapping()` can't work.

The second `QLineEdit` can't get data. as the picture show:

[image]

This is all the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from  PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QLabel, QDataWidgetMapper,
                              QLineEdit, QApplication, QGridLayout)
from PyQt5.QtCore import QAbstractListModel, Qt

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QListView


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)

        # Set up the widgets.
        self.nameEdit = QLineEdit()
        self.nameEdit2 = QLineEdit()

        layout = QGridLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.nameEdit, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.nameEdit2, 0, 2, 1, 1)

        self.setLayout(layout)

    def setModel(self, model):
        # Set up the mapper.
        self.mapper = QDataWidgetMapper(self)
        self.mapper.setModel(model)
        self.mapper.addMapping(self.nameEdit, 0)
        self.mapper.addMapping(self.nameEdit2, 1)
        self.mapper.toFirst()


class MyModel(QAbstractListModel):
    def __init__(self, data=[], parent=None):
        # super().__init__(parent)
        super(MyModel, self).__init__(parent)

        self.__data = data

    def rowCount(self, index_parent=None, *args, **kwargs):
        return len(self.__data)

    def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole, parent=None):

        if not index.isValid():
            return None

        if index.row() > len(self.__data):
            return None

        if role == Qt.DisplayRole or role == Qt.EditRole:
            return self.__data[index.row()][index.column()]

        return None

    def flags(self, index):
        flags = super(MyModel, self).flags(index)

        if index.isValid():
            flags |= Qt.ItemIsEditable
            flags |= Qt.ItemIsDragEnabled
        else:
            flags = Qt.ItemIsDropEnabled

        return flags

    def setData(self, index, value, role=Qt.EditRole):

        if not index.isValid() or role != Qt.EditRole:
            return False

        self.__data[index.row()][index.column()] = value
        self.dataChanged.emit(index, index)
        return True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    myModel = MyModel([['line 1', 'line1 col2'],
                       ['line 2', 'line2 col2'],
                       ['line 3', 'line3 col2'],
                       ['line 4', 'line4 col2']])

    mywindow = Window()
    mywindow.setModel(myModel)

    qlistview2 = QListView()
    qlistview2.setModel(myModel)

    mywindow.show()
    qlistview2.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. The question itself solved my problem:

[QDataWidgetMapper: wrong mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23352045/qdatawidgetmapper-wrong-mapping?rq=1)

I used the wrong parent model `QAbstractListModel`. `QAbstractTableModel` is perfect for my application. Maybe I can also change the orientation of `QAbstractListModel` but I don't know how.

[The final code](https://gist.github.com/zhanglongqi/32a87262bff37a7cd1f9)